# Python 3.2 palindrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, palindrome

I'm doing some python online tutorials, and I got stuck at an exercise:A palindrome is a word which is spelled the same forwards as backwards. For example, the word

racecar

is a palindrome: the first and last letters are the same (r), the second and second-last letters are the same (a), etc. Write a function isPalindrome(S) which takes a string S as input, and returns True if the string is a palindrome, and False otherwise.
    These is the code I wrote :

```
  def isPalindrome(S):
      if S[0] == S[-1]
        return print("True")
      elif S[0] == S[-1] and S[1] == S[-2] :
        return print("True")
      else:
        return print("False")
```

But, if the word is for example ,,sarcas,, , the output is incorect. So I need a fix to my code so it works for any word.

Comment: Why use if statements, you should try to make it more dynamic, to work with any size word.  Basically, split the word in half, loop, doing the comparison, any false ends the loop.

Comment: Splitting in half is tricky if the word has an uneven amount of characters. It's easier to just loop.

Comment: @Reginald: What you forgot is the "etc" in your description. You just check the two first and the two last, you need to check all of them, no matter how long it is.

Comment: The problem is that that I don't know how long it is, the input is any word. I wrote a function that finds the middle character from a word, but I fail to use it on these codee.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A one line solution but O(n) and memory expensive is :

```
def isPalindrome(word) : return word == word[::-1]
```

A O(n/2) solution that uses the same amount of memory is:

```
def palindrome(word):
   for i in range(len(word)//2):
         if word[i] != word[-1-i]:
                 return False
   return True
```

This is the trick  @LennartRegebro mentioned

Comment: Second solution shouldn't be: len(word)//2?

Comment: @AndréOriani's code works fine in Python 2, but in Python 3 you will indeed need `len(word)//2`, as that will round down to an integer. The `range` function will throw an exception if it gets a non-integer value, and rounding down is fine in this case, since you don't need to check the middle character of an odd-length word against itself.

Comment: Thanks @Blckknght for teaching one more thing about Python. I never formally learned Python. I just use it on personal projects because "it was definitely the language for the job" and it was always Python 2.x.  As my background is on C-like languages, I wrongly assume  that for python int/int==int. 

Reginald I updated the code to use the "//" operator

Comment: abusing `zip()`: `palindrom = lambda s: all(a == b for a, b, _ in zip(s, reversed(s), range(len(s)//2)))`. Note: all current solutions ignore Unicode issues e.g., to iterate over user-perceived characters instead of Unicode codepoints, you might need `chars = regex.findall(r'\X', s)`

Comment: Sorry but there is no such thing as  O(n/2). That's not how big Oh notation works. It's simply O(n). The notation only considers the variable part the changes with a growth in size and not the constant half. Although it is twice as efficient it still grows in O(n) which is how the notation works.

Comment: @jamylak I have to disagree. If you look for the definition on CLRS book it says **O(g(n))={f(n): there is positive constants c and n0 such that 0<=f(n)<cg(n) for all n>=n0}**. The definition does not impose any restriction on what g(n) may look like. When n->infinity, the constant factor 1/2 will become irrelevant. So people will just say O(n) as most of the time they will care about large n. By using O(n/2) I wanted to emphasize that second algorithm is slightly faster than the first one by a constant factor.

Comment: @AndreOriani I don't have CLRS with me right now but im sure I could find an example that proves you wrong. However this may just be a subjective issue

Comment: If this solution is really O(n/2) or O(n) is questionable. Doesn't `word[-1-i]` code cause the underlying code to iterate to the end of the word to find the length as Python run on top of C binaries and C uses nulls to mark the string endings. In order find the negative python index, C would need to find the null and backup to nth character from the end or not?

Comment: @codeaperature Python implementation uses structs such as`PyStringObject` and `PyUnicodeObject` rather than just a plain `char*`. Those structs have fields to store the string length, thus making it a constant time operation in contrast to classic `strlen()`. Check https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/#id3

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_palindrome(text):
    text = text.replace(' ', '')
    text = text.casefold()
    if list(text) == list(reversed(text)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
word='malayalam'
print(word==word[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check a word is palindrome or not in Python is as below:

```
var[::] == var[::-1]
```

But, it is very important to understand that Python creates a new copy of string when you do `var[::-1]`
Python internally don't know if the reverse will result in same string or not. So, it's coded in a way where it creates a new copy of it.
So, when you try `var[::1] is var[::-1]` you will get FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
S = input("Input a word: ")

def isPalindrome(S):
    for i in range(0, len(S)):
        if S[0 + i] == S[len(S) - 1]:
            return "True"
    else:
        return "False"
print(isPalindrome(S))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
def isPalindrome(S):
    l = len(S)-1
    for i in range(0,l):
        if S[i]!=S[l-i]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: you forgot to delete by 2: `for i in range(0, l / 2 + l % 2 )`. `%` is needed for the case, when `l` is even

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it using recursion is:

```
def isPalindrome(word):
  if len(word) <= 1: return True
  return (word[0] == word[-1]) and isPalindrome(word[1:-1])
```

Answer (score -1):

this is my solution
    S = input("Input a word: ")

```
def isPalindrome(S):
    for i in range(0, len(S)):
        if S[0 + i] == S[len(S) - 1]:
            return "True"
        else:
            return "False"
print(isPalindrome(S))
```

Answer (score -1):

This is beaten to death, but I have some ideas if Python is implemented in C. If ...

1. The code `word[::-1]` iterates to string end to make a copy which discounts the `word == word[::-1]` code speed and memory efficiency factors
2. Iteration to the word middle is better then comparing a full  word as characters were already tested - for odd words the middle letter is not to be tested
3. Additions and subtractions need to be used sparingly
4. Recursion is cool (and fun), but uses a lot of stack (unless optimized with `tail recursion` ... which likely becomes a for loop in the underlying code but less likely able to be flexible enough to impose code optimizations).
5. Bit shifts are traditionally faster than divides

The following is the code:

```
def isPalindrome(S):
    last = len(S)
    middle = last >> 1
    for i in range(middle):
        last -= 1
        if(S[i] != S[last]):
            return False
    return(True)


print("\n".join([str((word, isPalindrome(word))) for word in ["abcdcba", "abcdBba", "abccba", "abcBba", "a", ""]]))
```

which yields:

```
('abcdcba', True)
('abcdBba', False)
('abccba', True)
('abcBba', False)
('a', True)
('', True)
```

Comment: So many of your assumptions are downright wrong. `len` for all built-ins is `O(1)`; there's no C-style `NUL` terminated strings. `range` objects are *significantly* faster than hand-implementing your own `while` loop equivalent. `last -= 1` is not meaningfully slower than `last = last - 1`, they're both doing identical work since `int`s are immutable (though I'd prefer `-= 1` to avoid repeating yourself). CPython (the reference interpreter) doesn't optimize tail recursion. The only legit point you have is that `word[::-1]` performs a shallow copy, but avoiding it won't help 99.9% of the time.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - You are right about O(1) for len (as I looked up). And some of my other assumptions are wrong - I'll edit my work - Like I said these are ideas...