# how to define a palindrome

Tags: python, palindrome

I'm trying to define a palindrome. This is what I have so far but I'm not sure what is next can someone please help me.

```
def palindrome(x):

    if x % 2==0:
        index1=0
        index2=0
        aString=str(x)
        number=len(aString)
        index1=number / 2
        index2=number / 2 -1
    else:
        index1=0
        index2=0
        aString=str(aString)
        number=len(aString)
        index1=number / 2 +1
        index2=number / 2 -1
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'define a palindrome'? Are you checking if x is a palindrome? Its hard to understand your code because as it is there are some lines that don't run (aString = str(aString)).

Comment: If you are verifying that a string is a palindrome, then you could simply do `x[::-1] == x`. Otherwise, it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: palindromes typically ignore a difference of whitespace and punctuation too.  "A man, a plan, a canal – Panama!"

Comment: And use `.lower()` for case-insensitivity

Answer (score 2):

You could just try something like this :

```
sampleString[::-1] == sampleString
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def palindrone(x):
    return x == x[::-1]
```

For example:

```
>>palindrone("dad")
True
```

Answer (score 1):

For checking if a word/string is a palindrome, this is sufficient, although as [others have pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11759118/869912), it's a memory-expensive solution:

```
def ispal(s):
    return s == s[::-1]
```

To check if a number is a palindrome, several solutions exist (and my list is by no means exhaustive):

```
import math

def ispal(n):
    return str(n) == str(n)[::-1]

def ispal2(n):
    digits = math.floor(math.log10(n) + 1)
    for ex in range(1, math.ceil(digits/2)):
        leftdigit = math.floor(n / 10**(digits - ex)) % 10
        rightdigit = math.floor(n / 10**(ex - 1)) % 10
        if not(leftdigit == rightdigit):
            return False

    return True
```